# officejs : Unable to set underline property to false for hyperlinked text

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I inserted text and added a hyperlink to it. After doing this by default the text appears in blue color and underlined. I don't want the underline, but when I try to set the underline property to false, it has no effect on the text. You can find the sample code below.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var selection = context.document.getSelection();
    var para = selection.insertText("lorem", Word.InsertLocation.end);
    para.hyperlink = "https://www.stackoverflow.com";
    para.set({
    font: {
           underline: false
          }
    });
    return context.sync();
    }).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The values for Word's JS API `font.underline` property do not include `false`. Try with the string value `'None'`.

The accepted Enum values for `Font.Underline` are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.font?view=office-js#underline).

Note that the blue, underline formatting is Word's default style definition for the `Hyperlink` style. In the "COM" world the better approach would be to change the style definition to not include an underline. This option is not (yet?) available for JS Add-ins, which provide no functionality for changing or creating styles.